# Having trouble calling a ViewController with .xib file from storyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, xib

I have an application where I have a ViewController in my storyboard file.  I have added a button to this viewController that should call another ViewController that is outside of the storyboard and has with it, it's own .xib file.  However, when I press this button, the method is being called, but the new screen is not being loaded, and I don't know why.

Here is the relevant code that I have below:

```
- (IBAction)showTireCount:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"do i get called?");
    SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];

}
```

I am able to see the text "do i get called" appear in the system output, but unfortunately nothing else occurs.  Can anyone see what it is I am doing wrong?

Comment: When you put a breakpoint inside that method, and print `self.navigationController`, what do you see?

Comment: How do I print the contents of self.navigationController?  When I put a break point in the method, I don't see a reference to navigationController.

Comment: Use the `po` debugger command (print object), specifically, `po self.navigationController`, when halted in the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

self.navigationController is nil. Did you embed your view controller (the one with the button) in a UINavigationController?

Comment: That was my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are having the below statement inside SecondViewController initialize method

```
[super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
```